# How to set text leading or shift a text position on a TextView

Tags: android, android-studio

How do you set a text leading on a TextView? Or how do you shift a text position relative to a view that it is in?

I want the height of the textview to be less than what wrap_content would set at default without cutting the text from the bottom.

I've tried using the layout_height tag on its xml layout but it would clip the text from the bottom just like the image I've provided on the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGV4B.png) below, and I also have tried using the lineSpacingExtra tag but it seems to only work for the distance/leading between two lines.

Here is my xml file:

```
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp" 
        android:text="clipped text"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="-18dp"
        android:text="a text longer than usual to demonstrate line spacing"/>
```

Image for clarity: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGV4B.png

Answer (score 0):

Why you can use `wrap_content`? Or can you share what are you trying to achieve?

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="clipped text"/>
```

Comment: I want the height of the textview to be less than what wrap_content is at default without cutting the text from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do it using `padding` or `paddingTop` ? Try it with different values to get your desired result.

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:text="clipped text"/>
```